# query used in sub reporting

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports, subreport

```
Select 
    * 
From  
    EmploymentDetails a 
Left Join 
    PersonalInfo b 
On 
    a.cnic = b.cnic 
Left Join 
    Warning c 
On 
    a.cnic = c.cnic
Where 
    a.cnic = '{?cnic}'
```

This query displays result 4 times. How it will be resolved to display result only once against each `cnic`?

Comment: Add some sample data and expected results

Comment: Hint: [DISTINCT](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/distinct.php)

Comment: @AmmaraJaved Insert a group in your subreport and group your results by a.cnic. Then put the rest of your fields in the details section